# Format DateTime Data Display In Grid View

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime

I am trying to retrieve DateTime data type data from database in Asp.Net. Here is the code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dr["packingDate"].ToString());
```

However, the problem is the date I retrieved display in such format : 26/11/2013 12.00 AM . I just wanted to display the date but not the time. I'd tried to do this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dr["packingDate"].ToString());
string dateStr = date.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, it does not works in my grid view. I wonder why is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use the `DateTime.ToShortDateString` for this (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Could you please use whole words for your variable names? It would be courteous to the people reading the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could format on the `GridView` control, for sample:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="packingDate" HeaderText="PackingDate" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:dd-M-yyyy}"  />
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Almost forget can format it at the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in to string function for jsut the Date value...

```
DateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the corect type from database, so in this case `datetime`. Then you get a `DateTime` in your `DataTable` which you can cast with the `DataRow`'s `Field` extension method:

```
DateTime date = dr.Field<DateTime>("packingDate");
```

If you only want to diplay the date:

```
string dateOnly = dr.Field<DateTime>("packingDate").ToShortDateString();
```

or

```
string dateOnly = dr.Field<DateTime>("packingDate").ToString("d");
```

or

```
string dateOnly = dr.Field<DateTime>("packingDate").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```